# Make nautilus use default kde plasma color scheme

Tags: nautilus, plasma

I am currently working with the KDE Plasma window manager and switched my default file manager to nautilus. Functionally everything works, but aesthetically it looks not very pleasing. Is it possible to make nautilus use KDE Plasma's default color scheme?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use same colour scheme for both, as in Arch Linux based distros, there is `kde-gtk-config` (anything that provides `/usr/share/kcm-gtk-module/`, I guess. It adds GTK Settings in System Sttings) see what your disro have. Say if you are using `adwita` scheme for KDE, set the same for gtk from System Settings. Apperence > Application Style > Configure GNOME/GTK Application Style. You can download new schemes under that option and set them. Read more in [Arch](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Uniform_look_for_Qt_and_GTK_applications) [Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/KDE#GTK_application_appearance)